How do we prove that a parabola has only one axis of symmetry?
In this period I am trying to prove the basic properties of a parabola using Euclidean geometry and I'm having some problems now proving that a parabola has only one axis of symmetry.
Using Euclidean geometry, it is easy to show that a straight line passing through the focal point and perpendicular to the guide is an axis of symmetry of the parabola, the problem is to show that it is unique.
To prove this, I was trying to show that any other line is not a symmetry axis of the parabola.
I showed that there can't be an axis of symmetry parallel to the parabola guide because this contradicts the fact that every line perpendicular to the parabola guide cuts the parabola at exactly one point (I proved this separately and also I proved that not all parabola points can be in the range between two parallel lines)
I also proved that there can be no more than one axis of symmetry perpendicular to the evidence because this would contradict the fact that a parabola and a line cannot intersect at more than two points (I also proved this separately).
But my problem is with proving that there can't be an axis of symmetry, which is a straight line in the plane that is not parallel to or perpendicular to the parabola guide.
I think we can prove this by showing that this would lead to the parabola being a finite figure, which contradicts the fact that a parabola cannot be enclosed between two parallel lines and that every line perpendicular to the directrix of a parabola will intersect the parabola at exactly one point, but I still can't make my argument rigorous.
Can you make my argument formal or prove it in another way (geometric)?

Have you made use of the fact that if there are two lines of symmetry then 1) if they are parallel they imply a translation leaves the figure invariant 2) if they are not parallel they must intersect and then we must have a rotation at that point leaves the figure invariant?

I understand this, my problem is with turning that into a strict mathematical argument, I mean, I don't want visual intuition to be the reason for this to be true, I'm looking for a strict mathematical proof. @RobinSparrow

I'm not saying do it visually. If you have an arbitrary point equidistant to the focus and directrix,  it must remain so after a rotation or a translation, under the supposition of two axes of symmetry. That's grist for a proof.

What is a "parabola guide"? The directrix?

If we begin with premises you have already proven:

the line perpendicular to the directrix through the focus is an axis of symmetry
a line perpendicular to the directrix intersects the parabola one and only one time
an axis of symmetry cannot be parallel to the directrix

then we can prove there is one and only one axis of symmetry as follows.
Call the known axis of symmetry line $L_1$, the directrix line $D$, the the focus $F$. The vertex $V$ is by definition the midpoint of the projection of $F$ onto $D$ so $\frac{1}{2}FD=VD=VF=d$. Further, if multiple lines of symmetry exist, $L_1,L_2,L_3...$, we may serially reflect the figure about any combination of these lines while exactly preserving the figure, such that any point of the parabola, undergoing such serial reflections, always continues to lie on the locus of the parabola (perhaps not at the same location, perhaps so).
Suppose, for a contradiction, a second axis of symmetry, $L_2 \neq L_1$, existed. Either $L_1 \parallel L_2$ or $L_1 \nparallel L_2$.
If $L_1 \parallel L_2$ then a pair of reflections $(L_1L_2)$ must be equivalent to a translation $\vec{t} \parallel D$. But consider the vertex $V$, with initial distance to both directrix and focus $d=d_D=d_F$. Translation $\vec{t}$ on $V$ produces $V'$ with preserved distance $d'_D=d$ to the directrix but increased distance to the focus, i.e., $d'_D < d'_F$. This follows from the Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle{FVV'}$. Thus the point $V$' cannot lie on the parabola, so we cannot have $L_2 \parallel L_1$.
So $L_1 \nparallel L_2$. The intersection $I$ of these lines must lie on $L_1$, i.e., on the known axis of symmetry, call the acute angle formed there $\alpha$. We know the angle is acute because you showed a right intersection is impossible since an axis of symmetry cannot be parallel to the directrix. A pair of reflections $(L_1L_2)$ is therefore equivalent to a rotation $2\alpha \in (0,\pi)$ about $I$. And we may chain together as many such paired reflections as we please to produce rotations of $n2\alpha$. Stated differently, this implies that for any point $P$ on the parabola, another series of points $P',P'',..$ are also simultaneously on the parabola and on a circle of radius $IP$ with center $I$. Note that there are always $\geq 3$ such points. There are many routes to proceed from this juncture. For example, choose $P$ so that $IP>>ID$ to force some $P'$ to lie on the far side of the directrix from the parabola, or choose $P$ so $IP>IV$ so the vertex lies within the circle $IP$ and the parabola can intersect the circle only twice. Such choices of $P$ cause a perpendicular from the directrix to intersect the parabola twice, violating a theorem already proven, so $\lnot L_1 \nparallel L2$.
So no such $L_2$ can exist, so $L_1$ is the sole axis of symmetry of a parabola.

Beautiful proof, thank you

The case when the axis of symmetry of the parabola intersects the directrix but is not perpendicular to it: To prove the impossibility of this case, we start by defining the line $L$ that passes through $F$ and is perpendicular to $\Delta$. From the proof of Theorem 10, we know that $L$ is the axis of symmetry of $P$. Now, we select $M$ and $N$, two points on $P$ that satisfy the following three conditions:
First, the points $M$ and $N$ are distinct.
Second, neither $M$ nor $N$ is the vertex.
Third, the points $M$ and $N$ are not symmetric with respect to $L$.
We can observe that such points $M$ and $N$ exist because any line in the plane that is perpendicular to $\Delta$ will intersect $P$ at exactly one point, according to Theorem 5, and because not all points of $P$ can lie within the region bounded by two parallel lines.
Now, we draw the line $D$, which represents the perpendicular bisector of the points $M$ and $N$. To prove the theorem, all we need to do is show that $D$ cannot be an axis of symmetry of $P$. Let us do this...
We define the point $M'$ as the image of $M$ with respect to the line $L$. Since $L$ is an axis of symmetry of $P$, it follows that $M' \in P$.
Next, we define the point $M_1'$ as the image of $M'$ with respect to the line $D$. If we can show that $M \notin P$, this will prove that $D$ is not an axis of symmetry of $P$.

I haven't been able to prove it yet but it seems that what needs to be proven is that: $M_{1}'\in P⇔FN=FM_{1}'$
If I can prove it later, I will continue writing the proof, and if you can do so, please complete it.

A line can only be an axis of symmetry of a conic if it is perpendicular to the conic at each point of intersection between the line and the conic.
If this has not already been proved in your context, you would need to prove it. Conceptually, it is simple: if the curve crosses the line at an angle, the reflected curve will be in places near the line where the original curve was not.
Then you need only prove that any line other than the major axis of the parabola cannot intersect the parabola perpendicular to the curve at every point of intersection.
The difficulty with this kind of proof is that you need to know some properties of lines tangent to the parabola as well as other lines through the point of tangency. My recollection is that these properties can be proved with Euclidean geometry without resorting to calculus, but it takes some effort.
